# VBA Excel - Extract first 10 characters of entire column

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to extract the first 10 characters from all cells in an entire column (B-column). 
The cells are dates on the format:

2014-09-03  08:00:00

And I want all of them to be like this:

2014-09-03

My code looks like:

```
Sub AdjustDate()

Dim NewDate As String

For Counter = 1 To 1000000
    Set NewDate = Left(Cells(Counter, 2), 10)
    Cells(Counter, 2).Value = NewDate
Next Counter


End Sub
```

I am no master at VBA and I cannot figure out what I do wrong..

Would be thankful for help!

Comment: Does it work if you change `Set` to `Let`, or delete it completely?

Comment: So what is the error or behavior that you are getting?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just change the format of the cells? Why do you need to completely strip off the hours from the dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is used when assigning an object. Since a string variable is not an object `Set` should either be replaced by `Let` or left out all together.

In your case you wouldn't need to define the 10 first characters as a string variable and then replace the cell with the value of that variable. You could instead just do:

```
For Counter = 1 To 1000000
    Cells(Counter, 2).Value = Left(Cells(Counter, 2), 10)
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the formatting since the dates are typically stored as a number of days past Jan 1 1900 then formatted to be whatever you like

also agree with above, no need to use "set" in this situation w/o having an object to modify